# Is there any function to convert url

Tags: mediawiki

I wrote a function in the parser to grab JSON format file back and I want to convert the content to wiki URL, for example:

**JSON content**

[{"title":"a"},{"title":"b"}]

convert it to like what you type `[[a]]` `[[b]]` in the wiki

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about JSON to know if this helps, but I hope it does.

Emiliano Bruni has a (free) online HTML-to-Wikitext converter at:
http://www.ebruni.it/en/software/os/i_love_wiki/index.mpl

I have used it several times and it seems to work quite well.

~ Mark

EDIT: I got curious and poked around the interwebs some more and found two potentially helpful sources:

1) A Wikipedia help article, *Wikipedia:Tools/Editing tools*, with a list of *Wikisyntax conversion utilities*, including [HTML-to-MediaWiki conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tools/Editing_tools#From_HTML).

2) The (relatively) new *Visual Editor* available on Wikipedia (and other wikis using MediaWiki that choose to install it) has worked quite well for me since I started using it a few months ago, including for converting URLs to Wikitext. I recognize that *Visual Editor* has proven controversial among some Wikipedians, but I personally have found it easier to use than source editing or *wikiEd* (an in-browser text editor for sites using MediaWiki).